# How can I add og:image tags with Create React App without server side rendering

Tags: javascript, facebook, single-page-application, create-react-app

I just created a SPA with Create React App and need to allow users to share posts on Facebook.  I want the image preview to show up and be visible on Facebook, however it is not working because of a lack of SSR.

Is there a simple way to add og:image tags without a ton of work?

Comment: No that is not possible. Facebook doesn't execute Javascript.

Comment: You can add server-side rendering just for meta tags, and leave the rest of the app being rendered only on the client. Take a look here https://github.com/kriasoft/react-app